# Illegal instance declaration / Overlapping instances

Tags: haskell, overlapping-instances

Given class X and Y, what's the most idiomatic approach to creating instances of each other's class? e.g. -

```
instance (X a) => Y a where ...
instance (Y a) => X a where ...
```

I'd like to avoid extensions.  Also, I am aware that this could cause some nasty infinite recursion, so I'm open to a completely different approach to accomplish the same thing and stay relatively DRY.  Below gives some context as to the exact problem I am having -

```
data Dealer = Dealer Hand
data Player = Player Hand Cash

class HasPoints a where
    getPoints :: a -> Int

class (HasPoints a) => CardPlayer a where
    getHand :: a -> Hand

    viewHand :: a -> TurnIsComplete -> Hand

    hasBlackjack :: a -> Bool
    hasBlackjack player = getPoints player == 21 &&
                          (length . getCards . getHand) player == 2

    busts :: a -> Bool
    busts player = getPoints player > 21
```

I'd like to do this -

```
instance (CardPlayer a) => HasPoints a where
    getPoints = getPoints . getHand
```

But it seems I must do this -

```
instance HasPoints Dealer where
    getPoints = getPoints . getHand

instance HasPoints Player where
    getPoints = getPoints . getHand
```

**EDIT**

Seems my favorite approach is to keep the `HasPoints` typeclass and implement `CardPlayer` as `data` instead.

```
data CardPlayer = Dealer Hand | Player Hand Cash

instance HasPoints CardPlayer where
    getPoints = getPoints . getHand

getCash :: CardPlayer -> Maybe Cash
getHand :: CardPlayer -> Hand
viewHand :: CardPlayer -> TurnIsComplete -> Hand
hasBlackjack :: CardPlayer -> Bool
busts :: CardPlayer -> Bool

-- I wanted HasPoints to be polymorphic
-- so it could handle Card, Hand, and CardPlayer

instance HasPoints Hand where
    getPoints Hand { getCards = [] } = 0

    getPoints hand = if base > 21 && numAces > 0
                     then maximum $ filter (<=21) possibleScores
                     else base
      where base = sum $ map getPoints $ getCards hand
            numAces = length $ filter ((Ace==) . rank) $ getCards hand
            possibleScores = map ((base-) . (*10)) [1..numAces]

instance HasPoints Card where
    -- You get the point
```

Comment: But you need `HasPoints` as a separate class? You cannot just remove `HasPoints` and make `getPoints` an overloaded function with a `CardPlayer` constraint?

Comment: Type classes don't seem to have any use here; I suspect you should eliminate them completely from this module. Why not just `data CardPlayer = Dealer Hand | Player Hand Cash` then something like `getHand (Dealer hand) = hand; getHand (Player hand cash) = hand` and then `playerPoints = getPoints. getHand` and so forth?

Comment: @applicative - I like the `data CardPlayer = Dealer Hand | Player Hand Cash` approach.  However, I'd like to still use HasPoints so the getPoints function can be polymorphic.  Regardless, why wouldn't you suggest that as an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Given class X and Y, what's the most idiomatic approach to creating instances of each other's class?

The *most* idiomatic approach, given your example code, is to not use type classes in the first place when they're not doing anything useful. Consider the types of the class functions:

```
class HasPoints a where
    getPoints :: a -> Int

class (HasPoints a) => CardPlayer a where
    getHand :: a -> Hand
    viewHand :: a -> TurnIsComplete -> Hand
    hasBlackjack :: a -> Bool
    busts :: a -> Bool
```

What do they have in common? They all take exactly one value of the class parameter type as their first argument, so given such a value we can apply each function to it and get all the same information without needing to bother with a class constraint.

So if you want a nice, idiomatic DRY approach, consider this:

```
data CardPlayer a = CardPlayer
    { playerPoints :: Int 
    , hand :: Hand
    , viewHand :: TurnIsComplete -> Hand
    , hasBlackjack :: Bool
    , busts :: Bool
    , player :: a
    }

data Dealer = Dealer
data Player = Player Cash
```

In this version, the types `CardPlayer Player` and `CardPlayer Dealer` are equivalent to the `Player` and `Dealer` types you had. The `player` record field here is used to get the data specialized to the kind of player, and functions that would have been polymorphic with a class constraint in yours can simply operate on values of type `CardPlayer a`.

Though perhaps it would make more sense for `hasBlackjack` and `busts` to be regular functions (like your default implementations), unless you really need to model players who are immune to the standard rules of Blackjack.

From this version, you can now define a `HasPoints` class alone if you have very different types that should be instances of it, though I'm skeptical of the utility of that, or you can apply the same transformation to get another layer:

```
data HasPoints a = HasPoints
    { points :: Int
    , pointOwner :: a
    }
```

However, this approach quickly becomes unwieldy the further you nest specializations like this.

I would suggest droping `HasPoints` entirely. It only has one function, which just extracts an `Int`, so any code that handles `HasPoints` instances generically might as well just use `Int`s and be done with it.

Answer (score 6):

In general, [it's impossible to declare all instances of a class to also be instances of another class without making type checking undecidable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461029/declare-all-instances-of-a-typeclass-are-in-another-typeclass-without-modifying/8461108). So your proposed definition will only work with `UndecidableInstances` enabled:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}

instance (CardPlayer a) => HasPoints a where
    getPoints = getPoints . getHand
```

Although it's possible to go that route, I'd suggest refactoring the code as follows instead:

```
data Hand = ...

handPoints :: Hand -> Int
handPoints = ...

data Dealer = Dealer Hand
data Player = Player Hand Cash

class CardPlayer a where
  getHand :: a -> Hand
  ...

instance CardPlayer Dealer where ...
instance CardPlayer Player where ...

playerPoints :: (CardPlayer a) => a -> Int
playerPoints = handPoints . getHand
```